# Android Studio Error "output path is not specified for modules"

Tags: android, android-studio

I just recently upgraded to the newest version of Android Studio (0.1.1), but I also used Android Studio to relocate my project to my Dropbox folder. So, I'm not exactly sure which one is causing this problem.  When I build or try to run my project I get this error:

```
Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for modules
 "actionbarsherlock",
"EmPubLite-EmPubLite".
Specify the output path in Configure Project.
```

I can't find any reference to "Configure Project" and the Project Structure option under File no longer works in this release.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Solution for Android Studio version < 1.0 :**

You just have to go to your Modules settings > Project and specify a "Project compiler output"
and make your modules inherit from project. (For that go to Modules > Paths > Inherit project.

Or you can specify your output for each module if you want.

Comment: Please give full paths... Where is "Modules settings > Project" ??

Comment: Right click on your Project or Module > "Open Module Settings"

Comment: "Project compiler output" doesn't appear on Android Studio 1.2 Preview 2

Comment: @Andros "Project compiler output" It doesn't appear on new versions of Android....do you know where it is now?

Answer (score 23):

In order to do so you just need to follow this steps:

1. Open Project structure (F4 on one of the modules in the project explorer)
2. Click on Project tab on the left
3. Define "Project compiler output:" as YOUR_PROJECT_PATH\out (or any folder you want)
4. Click on Modules tab on the left
5. Go over all your modules and verify that under the Paths tab the Compiler output is set to "Inherit project compile output path"

Comment: The answer seems to be based on the accepted one (by Andros). Why do we need a rewrite of it? If it really matters, what's the main difference?

Comment: Thanks for the steps. @Alexey, This was the only answer that worked for me. The reason its different from the accepted answer is that they dont talk about the first three steps mentioned here. #3 was the main thing that made my error go away.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up re-importing the project using Gradle and it's back to normal. Very weird issue.

Answer (score 2):

this is a problem that I face in case I open my phonegap project with Android Studio and Webstorm.
They are IntelliJ-based project and I guess they are both writing the files in .idea

Reimporting the project is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

got same error while using studio feature to import from GitHub repository.
I deleted the whole project and .. cloned it using git terminal and imported as new project ... studio prompted to add VCS root, accepted  ....everything was fine afterwards. As *@lordhong* prompted.

Comment: pulling with git from terminal and using _Import existing project_ fixes the OP's problem, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

http://www.chrisdew.com/blog/2013/07/17/android-studio-nosuchmethoderror-lazystringarraylist/

it is realy help for me.

Thus, in my case, the problem was to have two libraries:

`protobuf-2.4.1.jar`
and new `protobuf-2.5.0.jar`

it resulted error:

`APK path is not specified for module “Example-Example”`

To correct this, rename file protobuf-2.4.1.jar to protobuf-2.4.1.jar.disabled

`mv protobuf-2.4.1.jar protobuf-2.4.1.jar.disabled`

Answer (score 1):

How I finally managed to fix after hours!
File -> Project Structure -> Facets -> choose module's facet -> Packaging. Enter in APK Path absolute path to apk to be created: C:\workspace\MyCompany\MyProject\myProject.apk
Press ok and run your project