# When I try to run my app back in Android Studio an “Edit Configuration”

Tags: android, android-studio, netbeans-plugins

I have a project files.i need to understand the flow of the project but When I try to run my app back in Android Studio an “Edit Configuration” tab appears and I have the options to update settings regarding the package, activity and target device however I am not sure what to select.

Has anyone else come across this problem? please help me

Comment: Build -> Clean did it for me.

Answer (score 12):

OK. I got you .

Please follow the steps below:

Click on File -> Project Structure ->(under Modules click on) app -> [Now you can select 'compile sdk version' and 'build tools version' accordingly from this window] -> click OK -> sync your project -> now clean and run the project.

NB: You have to choose the sdk version and build tools version - which is already downloaded in your android studio

Comment: Can you tell us why this happens? what is the proper way to upload the project to GitHub that it wont happened?

Answer (score 6):

1. It looks like you have not configured Android app, just click on the "Select Run/debug Configuration" which is on the left of RUN button and click on Edit Configurations. This will open a new screen where you can add a new configuration.
2. Another issue is, you might not have Sync the project.To sync the project, go to build.gradle file -> Sync Now. If it is not not working, then change accordingly and then press "Sync Now" or "Try again".
3. Also make sure that, if in case you have imported the modules, configure and import it correctly.And make sure that your build.gradle file is correct.
4. Re-opening the android studio worked for me once i got this issue.
5. In activity, select the Default Activity and in target device, Select whatever you are using(i.e Emulator or USB device).

Comment: I added the add configuration but after its showing "the output path is not specified for module "projectName".
Specify the output path in Configure Project."

Comment: i hope this would help @Sahal Zaman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828110/android-studio-error-output-path-is-not-specified-for-modules

Comment: Hi and thanks! File -> "Sync Project with Gradle files" did it for me (I had cloned an external project from Github).

Answer (score 3):

Simply Solve the problem just in one click i.e 
In Android Studio right side vertical "Gradel" option is there and click on "Refresh all Gradle Projects" (icon like refresh)

Answer (score 3):

Updating the libraries worked for me.
Go to the event log on bottom right and it will show the libraries which are outdated or not working properly !