# run a sample android Project

Tags: android

When I download an Android project, I don't know how I can run it.
As an example [I've downloaded this project](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

When I open it Android Studio says that:

[image]

After clicking the `Configure` button I see only:

[image]

After clicking `OK` button, I can see the project structure and there is no any error.

[image]

However, I cannot build or run this project.

[image]
[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

---

### EDIT -- NEW Images Added

[image]

### [image]

### EDIT -- LAST Status of the APP

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: That's not a gradle project, so you won't get the normal set of options to run

Answer (score 3):

Some Projects given by the guides are older and donnt have the gradle configuration to run properly on the newest version of Android Studio.

The recommendation is *never try to open in a normal way!!.*
You need import all the projects that you download, in that way Android Studio check and override configurations in project to run/Build properly.

I try import this porject and is working fine. All you need to do is Import and accept the sugestion that Android Studio popup to Update gradle.

***EDIT:***

You can import in 2 ways.

> Important !! Select folder project.

First window to select Project in AS. 
[image: Welcome window AS]

And the other way is when you have open the project just go File>New>Import Project

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please show me how you import it to your project? I am very new on Android so I don't know how I can add a project to my current project.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you have not yet told Android Studio what to run/how to run. Go to run->run...->app and then you will have to select an emulation device to run it on.

Comment: After your recommendation. Run button has been activated. But when I try to run it I'm getting new errors. I edited my question and added new screenshots. It can be related with Project default or something?

Comment: Can you please try to download the project and try to run it if you have Android Studio?

Comment: A question on the same error is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828110/android-studio-error-output-path-is-not-specified-for-modules).

Comment: I've taken one more step with your suggestion but unfortunately still I cannot run it.  Buil/Rebuild/Clean Project is still missing. I continue to work on it.

Comment: Are you able to run the project or are there any errors?

Comment: Unfortunately, mate, still not working.. I've added the last error in my original message.

Answer (score 1):

Restart android studio and Import the project OR give a try to these steps:

1. press **CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S**.
2. Under Project Setting go to **Facets**.
3. Click **+** button and add **Android-gradle**.
4. select your project name. click **apply** and ok.
5. close your project and reopen.